# Resharper 7: Sort Method by name, within a #Region

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper, region

I am trying to **sort** the methods by **name** that are in a class in a **#region**, is there a way?

```
#Region ABCD
   public void XYZ(){}
   public void ABC(){}
#EndRegion
```

Becomes:

```
#Region ABCD
   public void ABC(){}
   public void XYZ(){}
#EndRegion
```

Only those in the region (or if I have to, highlighted text) get sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but there is an option on `ReSharper-->Tools-->Cleanup Code-->Reorder type members`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try using CTRL-ALT-F i think, Code Cleanup. It will provide you with 2 default profiles that among other things will sort methods for you. You can define a profile that will suit your needs.